# Replace string if starts with string in List

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string that looks like this

```
s = "<Hello it´s me, <Hi  how are you <hay"
```

and a List
`List<string> ValidList= {Hello, hay}` I need the result string to be like

```
string result = "<Hello it´s me, ?Hi  how are you <hay"
```

So the result string will if it starts with an < and the rest bellogs to the list, keep it, otherwise if starts with < but doesn´t bellong to list replaces the H by ?

I tried using the *IndexOf* to find the position of the < and the if the string after *starsWith* any of the strings in the List leave it.

```
foreach (var vl in ValidList)
{
    int nextLt = 0;
    while ((nextLt = strAux.IndexOf('<', nextLt)) != -1)
    {

        //is element, leave it
        if (!(strAux.Substring(nextLt + 1).StartsWith(vl)))
        {
            //its not, replace
            strAux = string.Format(@"{0}?{1}", strAux.Substring(0, nextLt), strAux.Substring(nextLt + 1, strAux.Length - (nextLt + 1)));
        }
       nextLt++;   
    }
}
```

Comment: `Regex.Replace(s, string.Format("<(?!{0})", string.Join("|", ValidList)), "?")`

Comment: but in the case that has this string  `s = "<Hello it´s me < d" `   it doesn´t replace the <, that is alone

Comment: You didn’t specify at all what should happen with `<` that are not a prefix to a word. Nor did you give an example. Nor did you say anything about all the other edge cases I can think about.

Comment: @hiitsme Solution given @ poke will work perfectly fine for your case, [check this online](http://rextester.com/ZXTXL57954)

Comment: Perfect ! But can you explan what (?!{0}) means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give the solution I gave as a comment its proper answer:

```
Regex.Replace(s, string.Format("<(?!{0})", string.Join("|", ValidList)), "?")
```

This (obviously) uses regular expressions to replace the unwanted `<` characters by `?`. In order to recognize those characters, we use [a negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expression. For the example word list, this would look like this: `(?!Hallo|hay)`. This will essentially match only if what we are matching is not followed by `Hallo` or `hay`. In this case, we are matching `<` so the full expression becomes `<(?!Hallo|hay)`.

Now we just need to account for the dynamic `ValidList` by creating the regular expression on the fly. We use `string.Format` and `string.Join` there.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this without using RegEx or LINQ

```
        string s = "<Hello it´s me, <Hi  how are you <hay";
        List<string> ValidList = new List<string>() { "Hello", "hay" };

        var arr = s.Split(new[] { '<' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            foreach (var item in ValidList)
            {
                if (arr[i].Contains(item))
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = (flag) ? flag : !flag;
                }
            }

            if (flag)
                arr[i] = "?" + arr[i];
            else
                arr[i] = "<" + arr[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using LINQ.It splits the string using `<` and checks if the "word" (text until a blank space found) following is in the Valid List,adding `<` or `?` accordingly. Finally,it joins it all:

```
List<string> ValidList = new List<string>{ "Hello", "hay" };
string str = "<Hello it´s me, <Hi  how are you <hay";

var res = String.Join("",str.Split(new char[] { '<' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(x => ValidList.Contains(x.Split(' ').First()) ? "<" + x : "?"+x));
```